# GRANT EXECUTE not granting access to related tables in function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have user that should have access only for 2 functions, so I granted them to him:

```
REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION some_func(firstid INT) FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION some_func(firstid INT) TO some_user;
```

But I'm getting weird error:

```
42501: permission denied for relation some_table
```

when trying to access my function with:

```
SELECT * FROM offers_get(0);
```

My function looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.some_func(firstid integer)
 RETURNS TABLE(/* something */)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    /* something */
BEGIN
    /* some other logic */
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM some_table;
END;
$function$
```

So, access to related tables was not granted? How to grant access only for function execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to define the function using `SECURITY DEFINER` (see the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createfunction.html)).

By default, Postgres uses the permissions of the caller, not the definer.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.some_func(firstid integer)
 RETURNS TABLE(/* something */)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 SECURITY DEFINER
 . . .
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. Meow.